# Azure Data Lake gen 2 - change access tier - early deletion fee

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I need to change Archive access tier to Hot.
Are you able to explain early deletion fee?

I've changed access tier from Hot to Archive yesterday.
Does it mean that I'll pay for the storage twice (for Hot tier and during 179 days for an archive tier)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean that I'll pay for the storage twice (for Hot tier and
> during 179 days for an archive tier)?

Assuming you are going to keep the blob in `Hot` tier going forward, you will be paying the storage cost for the blob in Hot tier once the blob is rehydrated.

Also, because you did not keep the blob in `Archive` tier for minimum 180 days, you will be paying an early deletion fee. That would be the storage cost of the number of remaining days you should have kept the blob in Archive tier (179 days in your case).

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/access-tiers-overview#archive-access-tier):

> Data must remain in the Archive tier for at least 180 days or be
> subject to an early deletion charge. For example, **if a blob is moved
> to the Archive tier and then deleted or moved to the Hot tier after 45
> days, you'll be charged an early deletion fee equivalent to 135 (180
> minus 45) days of storing that blob in the Archive tier**.